# jquery easing images

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a vertical gallery. When you hover over an image, it slides out 300px from the left, and slides back in.

- I set a position:absolute and a width:400px. I want the images to stack-up vertically. Is this the correct way to do in this scenario?
- How do I make the jquery easeInSine/ease to work?

Thanks!

CSS

```
#gallery{
   display:block;
   width:400px;
   position:absolute;
   left: -5px;
}
```

HTML

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="_js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.slidingimage').hover(
                function () {
                    $(this).stop().animate({
                            left: '-5px',
                        },
                        500,
                        'easeInSine'
                    ); // end animate
                },
                function () {
                    $(this).stop().animate({
                            left: '300px',
                        },
                        600,
                        'easeOutBounce'
                    ); // end animate
                ); // end hover
            }); // end ready
</script>

<div id="gallery">
    <img class="slidingimage" src="images/gnu.jpg" height="200px" width="250px">
    <img class="slidingimage" src="images/tiger.jpg" height="200px" width="250px">
    <img class="slidingimage" src="images/black_rhino.jpg" height="200px" width="250px">
    <img class="slidingimage" src="images/cape_buffalo.jpg" height="200px" width="250px">
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for your code?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out. However, it is not working quite how I want to work. If anyone have suggestions on improving the functionality. That would be awesome. Thanks!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".slidingimage").hover(function() {
    $(this).animate( {"left": "+=300px"}, 2000, "easeInSine" ); 
    });

    $(".slidingimage").hover(function() {
    $(this).animate( {"left": "-=300px"}, 2000, "easeOutBounce" ); 
    });
});//end of document ready
```

Comment: Hi Manish, It works flawlessly. Thanks for sending this over!